# Showing Div ID on Scroll

Tags: javascript

I have this JS code that in a popup box shows the id value of the div when scrolling past it. It works fine when the id looks like this: id="1". But how can I change it to detect an id that looks like this: id="1:1" or id="23:4"? Two numbers separated by a colon.

```
<div id="sayverse"></div>
<div id="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et facilisis elit. Ut interdum, odio et aliquam tempor, felis odio auctor erat, eget elementum lectus arcu tempus elit.</div>

<div id="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et facilisis elit. Ut interdum, odio et aliquam tempor, felis odio auctor erat, eget elementum lectus arcu tempus elit.</div>

function findPosition( oElement ) { 
    if( typeof( oElement.offsetParent ) != 'undefined' ) { 
      for( var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent ) { 
      posX += oElement.offsetLeft; posY += oElement.offsetTop; } 
      return [ posX, posY ]; 
    } else { 
      return [ oElement.x, oElement.y ]; 
  } 
}

function functionThatSetsPosition() {
var scrolledFromTop = getScrollXY()[1];
var topposition, lastone, offsetFromTop, currentverse, firstVerse = 1;
while(!document.getElementById('vs'+firstVerse) && firstVerse < 10000) {
    firstVerse++;
}
for(var i = firstVerse, onediv; onediv = document.getElementById('vs'+i); i++) {
    topposition = findPosition(onediv)[1];
    offsetFromTop = topposition - scrolledFromTop;
    if( i == firstVerse && offsetFromTop >= 0 ) {

        currentverse = i;
        break;
    }
    if( offsetFromTop >= 0 && offsetFromTop <= 20 ) {

        currentverse = i;
        break;
    }
    if( offsetFromTop > 20 ) {

        currentverse = lastone;
        break;
    }
    //store this as the last one for checking afterwards
    lastone = i;
}
if( !currentverse ) {
    currentverse = lastone;
}
document.getElementById('sayverse').innerHTML = 'Verse '+currentverse;
```

}

Philip

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to detect the position of the element to determine the second value (the number after the :).

If that second number is your variable called offsetFromTop, then it could be added like so:

```
document.getElementById('sayverse').innerHTML = 'Verse ' + currentverse + ':' + offsetFromTop;
```

Comment: I think that gives me the Y coordinates as I scroll. I forgot to mention that the numbers in the id is prefixed with 'vs'. I include this code as it is part of the JS code to detect the scroll. I didn't include before because I didn't think it necessary.              `function findPosition( oElement ) {
 if( typeof( oElement.offsetParent ) != 'undefined' ) {
  for( var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent ) {
   posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
   posY += oElement.offsetTop;
  }
  return [ posX, posY ];
 } else {
  return [ oElement.x, oElement.y ];
 }
}`